# In the triage queue, if the comments ask the user for more information, should it be flagged?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, comments, triage

In the triage queue one comes across questions from all disciplines. If there are comments under the question asking the OP for more clarity, should I flag it as needing an author edit or should I skip it?

Comment: That depends. If it is genuinely information that is lacking in the Question for it to be answerable, and you know this for sure, then you should flag it for closure. If you are not sure, then Skip.

Comment: The comments are not important. Judge the question on its merits.

Comment: If you have to ask for a second opinion, you should probably be skipping.  If it's truly unclear,  you probably don't need a comment providing a second opinion (in advance).

Comment: commnets a re important, and it is bad that they are often deleted. i look always in the comments, because there are very often bits of useful information. but on endeffect you have to decide

Comment: @DanielWiddis While I don't disagree, I remember mods saying that Triage should not require any subject matter expertise. Often, unclear questions don't require a SME to judge them as such, but they occasionally do.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Right. Point I'm trying to make is, the purpose of many of the multiple-vote systems in most of the review queues is to get multiple *independent* users to make a judgment on a post. If the only reason I'm closing a post is because one other user said it wasn't clear, I'm not making that independent judgment.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That probably used to be true. Then the campaign of suspending users that did Triage wrong began some time back, and anyone that failed to pick "Unsalvageable" on a post that got closed, was suspended from review. This unfortunately included marking HowTo posts "Looks OK".

Comment: @DanielWiddis Those comments are very useful though. Especially for duplicate closures. I always check the comments to see if someone else has spotted something. Typos are often in comments as well. Since review suspensions are not imaginary, getting as much information before making a judgement means one can "review yet another day" ;)

Comment: @yivi "The comments are not important. Judge the question on its merits." To help with this we could show questions in triage without comments or score or name or rep. Just the content. That would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Reviews should be independent. Do your best to ignore other people's votes, flags and comments<sup>[1]</sup>.**

Consider the question in itself. If it's unclear, flag it. When in doubt, <kbd>SKIP</kbd>. Do not rely on the comments; rely on your judgement.

<sup>[1]</sup>*There are already methods for users who are not reviewers to flag the question (they can also leave comments, optionally). There is no need to count these comments and flags twice.*

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you see a post that has comments that read something like this:

> I'm voting to close this question because [close reason]

In such a case, here's what you would need to do:

1. Read the question. Does it actually need to be closed?  If so, then go ahead and flag it, since you don't have close privileges.
2. If the question seems fine to you, open it in a new tab and see who wrote the comment. If they seem knowledgable, then do number 3. If they don't seem to be an SME in the question's tags, then you may want to consider doing number 1, although keep number 3 in mind.
3. Skip. If you aren't sure, or don't want to risk failing an audit, then skip. I learnt that a user who skips a thousand times is doing more use to the site than a user who does 1000 reviews.

So if you see a comment like that, make sure to read the post. Don't just flag the post as soon as you see such a comment on a post.

---

Also, as noted [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403091/in-the-triage-queue-if-the-comments-ask-the-user-for-more-information-should-i/403098?noredirect=1#comment810051_403098), if you see a question that goes along the lines,

> What have you tried?

or something, just flag them as NLN. Because according to [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments), they need to be more specific, and if anything, add noise to the post.

Comment: It's not OK to leave a "What have you tried?" comment! They can be flagged. I'd pick "No longer needed". See [Is it OK to leave “What have you tried?” comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments) and [“What have you tried” epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)

Comment: @Scratte I made my meaning more clear.

Comment: I'd remove my comment.. but it kind of seem relevant to the thread. BTW: The comments I look for are clarifying questions such as "what is the definition of.. ?", "please post your html code too", "what error did you get?", "how didn't ... work?", "I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you clarify?", "you missed the r in 'String'".

Comment: It is relevant. It implies that if you see "What have you tried" comments, then you should flag them. I'll also add that in my answer. Also, fwiw, comments that ask more specific questions like, "Please elaborate on [this]" shouldn't really be deleted.

Comment: I agree they should not be deleted, especially not if they are specific. Until the post has been edited, and the comment is truly no longer needed :)

Comment: Just for the record: *SME* = Subject Matter Expert, *NLN* = No Longer Needed. - Not that obvious to me! (I would have suggested an edit, had I been allowed to.)